# Call BHO from javascript C#

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, bho

I have created a BHO(Browser Helper Object) for Internet Explorer. I have confirmed that the BHO works correctly by putting some basic action in the OnDocumentComplete handler and observing that it has the desired effect. I am now trying to call one of the methods from the BHO from java script.

I have found several sources that show how to do it which has resulted in the following code.

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
    IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)document.parentWindow;
    PropertyInfo pi = windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
    pi.SetValue(windowEx, this, null);
}
```

In my java script function I have the following:

```
function doWork() {
   try {
      alert(window.external.myExtension.GetSessionID());
   }
   catch(err) {
      alert(err.message);
   }
}
```

When I call this java script function (as the result of a button click) an exception is thrown and I get the message "Unable to get property 'GetSessionID' of undefined or null reference"

I have been to several pages that say they explain how to do this. All of them are either in C++ (which I haven't used in like 8 years and does not fit the requirements for my task) or refer back to pages that I have already seen and didn't help(many of theme here on Stack Overflow).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually - what you have looks correct. what is `this`? Are you sure that `OnDocumentComplete` is run (try adding a execScript with an alert to verify it)?

Comment: 'this' is my class BHO that implements the IObjectWithSite interface.

I am sure that OnDocumentComplete is called because the original example I started from had looped over all "INPUT" elements of the current page and showed a message box of the element name. That worked every time I went to any web site so I know.

What do you mean by "adding a execScript" to verify? Sorry my javascript knowledge is pretty limited at this point.

Comment: I meant calling execScript from C# to run JavaScript code on the client which would `alert` that it works.

Comment: I added the following call in OnDocumentComplete IHTMLWindow2 win = document.parentWindow;
            try
            {
                win.execScript("window.external.myExtension.GetSessionID()", "javascript");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                WF.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
A message box with an exception showed(which shows that OnDocumentComplete is called). The exception was "Access Denied." followed by an HRESULT hex code.

Comment: Just to add. I did try win.execScript("alert(\"TEST\")", "javascript"); That DID work.